# Use border and border radius on the same widget

Tags: flutter, border, border-radius

everyone how can i get like this icon's border in flutter
i need to set color only for left , bottom and top sides
i heard someone talk about customPainter but i don't nkow how to use plz help me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA3Hz.png)

this my code:

```
Container(      
   decoration:BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
     border: new Border(
      left: BorderSide(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      width: 2,),
      right: BorderSide(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      width: 2,),
      bottom: BorderSide( color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      width: 2,),
      top: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      width: 2,),),
       ) ,
      child:ClipOval(
      child: Image.asset('images/imageout1.png',width: 85,), 
                                                ))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you can use a `CustomPainter`. The key is the use of [drawArc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawArc.html)

**Return this somewhere in your widget build method**

```
CustomPaint(
    size: Size.square(100),
    painter: CirclePainter(),
)
```

**Create `CirclePainter`**

```
class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint innerLine = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0;

    Paint outerLine = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.orange
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0;

    canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), radius: size.width / 2),
        0, 2 * pi, false, innerLine);

    canvas.drawArc(
        Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), radius: (size.width + 12) / 2),
        1.9 * pi,
        1.2 * pi,
        false,
        outerLine);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

**Result**

[image]